# Is it possible to reindex specific blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I came across a block on my Fullnode that throws an error when attempting the `gettrawrtransaction` RPC.

`No such mempool or blockchain transaction. Use gettransaction for wallet transactions.`

It's only one block so far that seems like it got corrupted or improperly indexed. If I change the block/transaction, the JSON-RPC call works. I have `txindex=1` set in `bitcoin.conf`

My question is, can I tell `bitcoind` to reindex only that particular block `282455`, or do I need to reindex the entire blockchain? If so, what's the fastest method? Setting a higher `dbcache`?

Comment: can you see your transaction in that block?

Comment: none of the transactions in that block work with `getrawtransaction`. They aren't my txs. I'm just trying to get the raw data on them, similar to a blockchain explorer.

Comment: Can you give the txid of one of the transactions that fails for you?

Comment: @NateEldredge `e73da0c9a5548e62c73b5b297f33ab7605079bcdb00ca8c5afd56bfae835a88c` or any tx in the `282455` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to the best of my knowledge there is no user-level command to reindex specific blocks.  It's all or nothing.

If you want such a feature you'll have to write the code.

It seems to me kind of unlikely that the index would be wrong only for one specific block, so I would suggest looking for other explanations for the behavior you're seeing.